# Button calling ID from External Script

Tags: javascript

I am trying to code a game which calls an external .js script when the button is clicked. The code works the way I want it to, but I am a little confused about how to get the output into HTML so that it can be formatted properly. The button should restart the process whenever it is clicked (i.e. without having to reload the page), so that there is a new random selection made.

I eventually want to also include a button to remove the last-displayed item, but that is for later....

Javascript:

```
var basket = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry', 'durian', 'eggplant', 'fig', 'grapes', 'huckleberry', 'kiwi', 'lemon', 'mango'];

function randOrd(){
return (Math.round(Math.random())-0.5); } 

mixedBasket = basket.sort( randOrd ); //randomize the array

var i = 0;  // the index of the current item to show

fruitDisplay = setInterval(function() {            
document
    .getElementById('fruit')
    .innerHTML = mixedBasket[i++];    // get the item and increment
if (i == mixedBasket.length) i = 0;   // reset to first element if you've reached the end
}, 70);  //speed to display items

var endFruitDisplay = setTimeout(function( ) { clearInterval(fruitDisplay); }, 3000); 
//stop display after x milliseconds
```

The current HTML obviously runs the code, but it starts before the button is clicked.

HTML:

```
<head><script type="text/javascript" src="Fruitpicker3.js"></script></head>
<body>
<span id = "fruit"> </span>
<input type="button" onclick="fruit" value="Start"/>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `setInterval` call is not inside of a function, so when the .js file is downloaded and executed, it executes that method right away. The simplest solution is to wrap the call to `setInterval` inside of a function, and then call that function in the button's `onClick` event.

Comment: Thank you! I'd been banging my head against this for two days.

Comment: If this has answered your question, please mark it as correct (the hollow check-mark to the left. Thanks!